# How to develop a mobile application retrieving data from an Azure Website

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, azure, mobile-application, bizspark

I have developed a MVC 5 internet application and have deployed this to Azure. I am now wanting to develop and finish a mobile application that will retrieve the data from my MVC application and display the data in a mobile application.

How is the best way to do this? Should I use the Azure Mobile App Service, write the code myself in Xamarin or something else?

My mobile application needs to do the following:

1. Display MapMarkers on a Google Map.
2. Display information on each MapMarker when clicked on in the Mobile
   App.
3. Display GridViews and Lists of images and text.

I have written a basic application in Xamarin that does the above, but before I totally focus on writing the code myself, I would like to know the easiest way to develop a Mobile Application. I am currently getting the data from my MVC application from a webservice, and then displaying the data in an Android application.

I have also reached the end of my free trial in Xamarin, and cannot continue. The error being displayed states that I need an Indie or higher license. I am also a current member of the BizSpark subscription.

So, basically, I am wanting to know the easiest (and cheapest) way to develop a Mobile Application that retrieves data from a MVC application that I have developed. How many different ways can this be achieved? Is there a template service that will output Android code that I can then edit and customize to my liking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have web development skills, you can use Apache Cordova / Phonegap and build mobile apps with HTML5 / CSS3:

http://cordova.apache.org

http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to confine to Android only, then you can use Android development environment or you can go for Phonegap.

Whether it is IOS or Android, native language development is always the best if you have the time and resources to spend. Cross platform tools like phonegap are good to start but not 100% perfect.

This link may not say great things about Phonegap but you will get an idea on the types of challenges you may face in developing a cross platform app.

http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2013/03/ask-lh-should-i-use-phonegap-to-build-mobile-apps/

question: Do you have bizspark plus or just bizspark?